# Progressive Web App Template

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I would like to know if you can recommend a progressive web app template I can use from the scratch.

As I am new to this I am looking forward something that it usable by a starter and does not require advance programming, complex terminal instructions and commands to install and use.

Comment: Easiest to get going is Google Workbox. Now at version 4.0, but here's a nice 3.0 5 minute intro: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/a-5-minute-intro-to-workbox-3-0-156803952b3e

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample to start with your first [Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#introduction).

What you will build

> In this codelab, you're going to build a Weather web app using
>   Progressive Web App techniques. Your app will:
>
> - Utilize and demonstrate the above principles of Progressive Web Apps.
> - Use live weather data.
> - Provide app-like interactions to allow the user to add cities.

What you'll learn

> - How to design and construct an app using the "app shell" method
> - How to make your app work offline
> - How to store data for later offline use

What you'll need

> - A recent version of Chrome. Note, this works in other browsers as well, but we'll be using a few features of the Chrome DevTools to
>     better understand what's happening at the browser level.
> - Web Server for Chrome, or your own web server of choice
> - [The sample code](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/your-first-pwapp/archive/master.zip)
> - A text editor
> - Basic knowledge of HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and Chrome DevTools

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

See this pwa example on github.

https://github.com/steffstefferson/pwa-example

It is a simple example application that can be used to start off. Just copy the app folder to your local webserver and you will have a running pwa.

To understand how pwa works I recommend jake's cookbook:

https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/

Comment: Thanks! Will do. But quickly, what does this basic app do?

Comment: No worry. I saw it is a news site.

Comment: Yes, it basically displays a rss feed. So it should be possible to configure your own rss feed url in feedReader.js